# Android String File equivalent in iPhone(Monotouch)

Tags: android, iphone, string, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In android we have files by name String. Developers define the string values that they used for naming objects in this file. This is a very useful way. Because avoid of hard coding string values(you can change them from a single file, less time to change), also useful to creating multi language application and etc. (for more info just google this).

But the question is this: whether iPhone(Monotouch) have a mechanism like this to define strings on them or developers have to define themselves mechanism for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode, you'll find File/New File, then on the left, pick "Resource", and you'll find "Strings File".

From code, you'll be referencing the keys in your strings file with `NSLocalizedString`:

```
NSLog("%@", NSLocalizedString(@"YOUR-STRING-KEY-OR-DEFAULT-VALUE", @"Comment about what this is"));
```

For details on what that second param is for, [What is the second parameter of NSLocalizedString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442822/what-is-the-second-parameter-of-nslocalizedstring)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also i found more information in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830965/how-does-monotouch-manage-resources-strings-images-etc

Answer (score 0):

Put your strings in a single file. Make them global constants. Access them throughout the app. When you change these, the change will be reflected everywhere.

It's not a big deal to have persistent string references throughout your app. It can be done in any decent programming language and platform I suppose.